# MS Access 2010 Data Entry Form unable to Enter Data

Tags: ms-access-2010

The data entry form in My DB 2010 will not allow anything to be entered. If I make DataEntry to YES, the from is blank. If I change it to NO, it displays the typing fields, but I cannot enter anything. I have also made Additions and Edits to YES.

The DB is linked to another DB stored in a network where I have only read only access. When I copy the DB from the network to my local machine and relink the tables, the data entry form works fine. I need this DB to work from the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using bound forms, which in a shared environment isn't best practice, but the root issue is that you only have read access to the back end database.  You'll have to request read/write entitlements to the folder location that contains the back end database.  Another option would be move the back end database to a new location where users do have read/write access.  Lastly, you could always link the tables using an entitlement that does have read/write access.